# installing hackage package with stack (not in LTS or nightly)

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack, cabal-install

I'm getting started with stack, and I'm not entirely sure how to pull in a package that appears in hackage but not in the curated builds.

In particular, I'd like to pull in [thrift-0.10.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/thrift). It seems I can't specify it in my `project.cabal` file, nor does the `extra-deps` section work since there is no resolver that contains this package.

When I run `stack install thrift-0.10.0`, I receive the following error:

```
While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:
In the dependencies for thrift-0.10.0:
    vector-0.11.0.0 must match ==0.10.12.2 (latest applicable is 0.10.12.2)
```

I'm not really sure (a) what `stack install` does, and (b) how to resolve the build plan since the thrift package specifies an equality (==) on the vector-0.10.12.2 package. If I try and include the relevant `vector == 0.10.12.2` in my `package.cabal`, that also fails. Do I need to specify an earlier resolver?

I realize I have much to learn about this build tool, but in this case, my primary question, for which no documentation seems readily available is:

> how do I include a hackage package in my stack build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nor does the extra-deps section work since there is no resolver that contains this package.

extra-deps can contain any hackage package.

> (a) what stack install does

It just does a build of the package + copying of executables to .local/bin

Install shouldn't be used for dependencies, instead it should be used for your local project / applications from hackage (packages with executables).  There is no benefit to installing the dependencies of your project, instead they should be specified in stack.yaml

> (b) how to resolve the build plan since the thrift package specifies an equality (==) on the vector-0.10.12.2 package.

It seems really ugly for the thrift package to have an (==) constraint like that.  To get around it either do "allow-newer: true" in your stack.yaml (causes constraints to get ignored).  Or, probably better, add `vector-0.10.12.2" to your extra-deps.

> for which no documentation seems readily available is:
>
> how do I include a hackage package in my stack build?

See this section of docs: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#external-dependencies

Comment: Appreciate it. Can't believe I missed the external-dependencies section...doh!